# Where can I find the address to mypage@facebook.com?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

What didn't work so far:

- Sending an email to the exact page slug followed by @facebook.com
- Sending a message to an email from the page. The option is not available.

I'm looking for something similar to [this](https://www.facebook.com/help/224049364288051) but for pages:

Comment: Have a look at this source https://www.facebook.com/help/207097142662705

Answer (score 1):

Facebook never did offer @facebook.com email addresses to pages, only people, and that service was retired some months ago. (Email sent to yourname@facebook.com will get forwarded to your email address on file, at least for now.)

There used to be a feature to post to your Facebook Page via email, but that service, too, has been retired.